# print a print document appear different from print document preview c#

Tags: c#, image, printing, size, document

This is my problem:

I have a print document on my c# program.
When i see the print preview dialog of print document all appears correctly but when i print this document the image on the document appear oversize and cut on the edge. 
I try on my pc (Windows 7 1920x1080) all works correctly but when i try to print same document on my second pc (Windows 8 1366x768) i have this problem.....

I try to change Graphics.PageUnit to Point from Display but it always not work...

Draw image extract of my programm

```
        Rectangle logo = new Rectangle(x, yLogo - 11, 136, 67);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penTransparent, logo);
        try
        {  
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(settaggi.pathLogo().ToString()), logo);
        }
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

P.S.: If i try to print it with virtual printer like PDF24 all appears correct

Comment: Pay attention to the selected paper size.

Comment: Selected paper size of Print document? I set it to
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;
                printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 595, 842);

But its the same on Windows 8pc